# Entity Framework long running query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In my DB there is View "RqstLst"
I create EF Model from DB. Now I have entity RqstLst.

There is two variant of the same query

```
public void MyMethod()
{
     context = new WaterMEntities();
     var query = context.RqstLst;
     dgRqstLst.ItemsSource = query;  //dgRqstLst - DataGrid in WPF
}
```

and

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    dgRqstLst.ItemsSource = this.GetRqstLst();
}
private IEnumerable<RqstLst> GetRqstLst()
{
        context = new WaterMEntities();
        string nativeSQLQuery = "SELECT  * " +
                                    "FROM dbo.RqstLst ";
        ObjectResult<RqstLst> requestes =
            context.ExecuteStoreQuery<RqstLst>(nativeSQLQuery);
        return requestes;
}
```

execution time for first variant(LINQ to Entities) is 19 sec, for second, less then 1 sec.
I look it in sql server profiler. What i do wrong in first variant?

Comment: as a complete side issue/observation; people who take vowels out of words and use them as Data Table/View names (i.e. RequestList -> RqstLst) should be taken out and shot ;)

Comment: i already have view RequestList. RqstLst just for testing. So sorry but "shot" maybe another time and for another reason..;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference is that `ExecuteStoreQuery` doesn't attach the returned objects to the context (at least not the overload you are using) but your first query does (which costs time).

Try to define the same tracking behaviour in your first query like you have in the second query (= `NoTracking`):

```cs
context = new WaterMEntities();
context.RqstLst.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; // in System.Data.Objects
var query = context.RqstLst;
dgRqstLst.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: Certainly worth doing where necessary, but I can't imagine that being the source of an 18 second delay. Plus he mentions using the sql server profiler to see the execution time, which indicates the slowdown isn't from post processing.

Comment: @Ocelot20: I also don't really believe that it makes 18 sec. Sorry, I didn't notice mention him that the exec time in SQL already is different. (He could show the difference in SQL.) Your answer is a good guess though!

Comment: @Slauma, thanks. It realy help. now execition time is the same as in the first and second option

Comment: Guess that disproves my theory, hah. The hints in the question were a bit misleading, I guess the time difference was between the entire processing and not just the SQL.

Comment: @AntonLysogorsky: This is interesting. I have never seen such a big effect of `NoTracking`. Is the result list of your query very large (so that a lot of objects must the tracked in the context)?

Comment: @Ocelot20, yes so long time is for entire processing. Sorry for misleading;)

Comment: @Slauma, the result list is about 23000 objects

Comment: @AntonLysogorsky: OK, that's a lot and might explain the big effect of `NoTracking`. BTW, since you are new here: You can "accept" answers if they solved your problem (click on white check mark left from the answer) to indicate for others that the problem is solved.

Comment: @Slauma, oops. done. that's my first question on stackoverflow. and realy helpful reply)))

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do anything *wrong* with the first option, but depending on your configuration, the query generated by the first one could be much more complex than your straight SQL execution. Have you used the profiler to see exactly what SQL the first query generates? For example, if RqstLst happens to be an abstract base class using TPT Inheritance, the generated SQL could be huge.

Comment: yes i used profiler to what realy happens on 'dgRqstLst.ItemsSource = query;' then copied it and execute in managment studio. It executed less then 1 sec